# Is URL.openStream() the same as respone.getEntity().getContent()?

Tags: java, apache, file, http, inputstream

There is a file that will be downloaded when I make a `get` request to particular `URL`. I am able to get `InputStream` from both ways.

**Method 1**

Using `URL` class in `java.net` package.

```java
java.net.URL url = new URL(downloadFileUrl);
InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
```

**Method 2**

Using `Apache`'s `HttpClient` class.

```java
org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient httpclient = new CloseableHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute((HttpUriRequest)request);
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Are these methods the same? If not how? Which method is preferred generally or in a specific situation?

The examples I provided are simplistic. Assume I did the neccessary 
congifurations with the `URL` and `HttpClient` objects to get successful response.

Comment: They are equivalent, error behavour aside.

Comment: Note that other APIs, such as Spring RestTemplate, might provide a `getContent()` that returns a retrieved data object rather than a live `InputStream`; it's important to be clear about `HttpClient` in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods returns the input stream to read from the connection. There isn't difference between these methods. Since HttpClient is third party library, you need to keep a check for any vulnerabilities and keep updating the library.

Only difference is HttpClient supports only HTTP(s) protocol, whereas URLConnection can be used for other protocols too like FTP

In terms of functionalities, Apache HttpClient has more fine tuning options than URLConnection